# Easiest way to communicate with Bitcoin core with terminal (not bitcoind and without bitcoin core's terminal)?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-cli

I have bitcoin core running. I installed it through bitcoin.org and installed via a dwg file. I want to use bitcoin-cli commands through my mac's terminal app. (not with bitcoin core's terminal). I tried cd into bitcoin core's file(which is in ssd because the lack of available space) and tried bitcoin-cli but it didn't work. Is there a way to talk to my bitcoin node through terminal (not with bitcoind)

Basically, I want to do bitcoin-cli operations from my mac terminal after running bitcoin-core

[image]
[image]

Comment: This appears to be a dependency problem. It may be solved by upgrading to 22.0.

Comment: I upgraded but it didnt solve the problem. Isn't there a way to speak to bitcoin-qt from operating system's terminal but not bitcoin-qt's console?

Comment: Sure, it's just JSON-RPC, there are frameworks in most programming languages that speak that. But this is a bizarre result. Bitcoin Core doesn't use openssl anymore, so I don't see why it is depending on it. Is there any chance you have an old bitcoin-cli, and it's using that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstalling and reinstalling openssl library (via homebrew) solved the problem somehow.